# Why does Spring's RestTemplate has setters when Spring also provides RestTemplateBuilder class to build RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

The following are the methods:

1. public void setMessageConverters(List> messageConverters)
2. public void setErrorHandler(ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler)
3. public void setDefaultUriVariables(Map uriVars)
4. public void setUriTemplateHandler(UriTemplateHandler handler)

I was expecting that RestTemplate would be immutable.

Does it mean that we are not meant to reuse a singleton bean of RestTemplate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spring provides the `RestTEmplate` whereas Spring Boot provides the `RestTemplateBuilder`. One builds on top of the other. Finally `RestTemplate` predates the `RestTemplateBuilder`. You still need a way to configure the `RestTemplate` hence the setters. Yes you shold reuse a single instance, no you shouldn't call those setters more then once (inside an `@Bean` method to configure it).

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate is not thread-safe. But you can have thread-safe behaviour if your code avoids invoking non-threadsafe methods(setters) after it is constructed.
We definitely should not mutate the state of RestTemplate and reuse it.

Comment: Actually `RestTemplate` is perfectly thread-safe in using it (the request methods like `exchange`,  `getForObject`. You can use a single instance in multiple threads. However you shouldn't change the colaborators (like interceptors etc.) after construction. This applies to all templates in Spring like `JbdcTemplate`, `JmsTemplate` etc. as well.

Comment: I don't think we can say it is "perfectly thread-safe" if by design it allows mutating its state after construction without any synchronization mechanism.

Comment: That applies to every singleton and not specifically this case. THe use is perfectly thread-safe and you shouldn't modify it iafter construction.